# PYTHON: Sending email with an attachment that updates every 15 minutes

Tags: python, email, while-loop, automation

Below is a section of my code, it is in a while true loop to collect CO2 and Temperature readings from sensors every 15 minutes. It exports the data to a new CSV file every 15 minutes. The file name changes every 15 minutes as there is a date and time stamp required in the file name.

Can python be used to send an email with the CSV file attached if the file name is constantly changing?

I found the example below the dashed line online but the file location would be changing every 15 minutes in my case

```
for device in list_of_devices: 
        print (device)


for url_CO2 in list_of_urls_CO2:
        headers = CaseInsensitiveDict()
        headers['Accept'] = 'application/json'
        headers['Authorization'] = bearer_token

        resp_CO2 = requests.get(url_CO2, headers=headers)
        response_CO2.append(resp_CO2.text)

        print(resp_CO2.text)

for url_RT in list_of_urls_RT:
        headers = CaseInsensitiveDict()
        headers['Accept'] = 'application/json'
        headers['Authorization'] = bearer_token

        
        resp_RT = requests.get(url_RT, headers=headers)
        response_RT.append(resp_RT.text)

        print(resp_RT.text)

# importing pandas as pd  
import pandas as pd  

    
# dictionary of lists  
myDict = {'Device': list_of_devices, 'CO2 Level': response_CO2, 'Room Temperature': response_RT}  
    
df = pd.DataFrame(myDict) 

# saving the dataframe 
df.to_csv('test_{}.csv'.format(datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H.%M.%S")), index=False) 
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email import encoders
import os.path

email = 'myaddress@gmail.com'
password = 'password'
send_to_email = 'sentoaddreess@gmail.com'
subject = 'Town Farm Data Log'
message = 'Please see attached CO2 levels and Room Temperatures for Town Farm Classrooms'
file_location = 'C:\\Users\\You\\Desktop\\attach.txt'

msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['From'] = email
msg['To'] = send_to_email
msg['Subject'] = subject

msg.attach(MIMEText(message, 'plain'))

filename = os.path.basename(file_location)
attachment = open(file_location, "rb")
part = MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream')
part.set_payload((attachment).read())
encoders.encode_base64(part)
part.add_header('Content-Disposition', "attachment; filename= %s" % filename)

msg.attach(part)

server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
server.starttls()
server.login(email, password)
text = msg.as_string()
server.sendmail(email, send_to_email, text)
server.quit()
```

Comment: what is the problem to change name when you attache file? If you save file then you know its name and you can use it in email. Eventually you can save data in  file with new name and at the same time save it in file with name `latest.txt` so later you have to get only `latest.txt` to send newest data. On Linux you could simply create link `latest.txt` which redirect to the newest filename. But you may put name of last saved file inside file `latest.txt` and read this name from `latest.txt` when you will send email

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to keep your files after send, it's easy to do like this:

Put your sending email code into the function named `send_by_email` for example

Then just collect all the files in the target dir, filter only csv-s  and send them one by one (don't forget to delete file after send not to get into eternal loop on next iteration)

```py
import os

mypath = '/tmp'                                         # define path to dir with your files
filenames = next(os.walk(mypath), (None, None, []))[2]  # list all files
csvs = [f for f in filenames if f.endswith('.csv')]     # fileter only .scv files

for filename in csvs:
    file_with_path = os.path.join(mypath, filename)
    send_by_email(file_with_path)
    os.remove(file_with_path)
```

If you need to keep files, you can just move them into another dir instead of deleting.